# iOS Error Creating Contact

Tags: contacts

I'm using the following code to create a contact:

```
CNContactRelation *rel = [[CNContactRelation alloc] initWithName:@"John"];
CNLabeledValue *lv = [[CNLabeledValue alloc] labeledValueBySettingLabel:@"_$!<Friend>!$_" value:rel];

NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];
[arr addObject:lv];

CNMutableContact *contact = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];
contact.givenName = @"Joe";
[contact setContactRelations:arr];

CNSaveRequest *request = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
[request addContact:contact toContainerWithIdentifier:nil];

NSError *saveError;
if (![store executeSaveRequest:request error:&saveError])
        NSLog(@"error = %@", saveError);
```

I get this error on saving:

```
error = Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={CNKeyPaths=(
contactRelations)}
```

If I remove the line that sets the contact relation ([contact setContactRelations:arr]), then the contact is created just fine.

Would anyone know what's wrong with the contact relations array, or is setting this not allowed?

Comment: i'm facing the same problem here. Do did You have any solutions?

Comment: No I'm afraid I didn't. The feature that needed this was removed from the app so did not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me. Swift 3.1. Must import 'Contacts'

```
 let store = CNContactStore()
 let contact = CNMutableContact()
 contact.givenName = "first Name"
 contact.familyName = "Last Name"

 let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelWork, value:"EMAIL" as NSString)
 contact.emailAddresses = [workEmail]

 let homePhone = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelWork, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue :NUMBER ))
 contact.phoneNumbers = [homePhone]



 let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
 saveRequest.add(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier:nil)
 try! store.execute(saveRequest)
```